# Query search after user has typed for a few seconds Meteor + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I am implementing a search component that I want to only execute after a user has typed for a few seconds so I am not querying the db on every key input. Not sure in which block to execute a `_.debounce` or `setTimeout`.

I am using `react-komposer` and here's what it looks like

```
import { composeWithTracker } from 'react-komposer';
import { Ruuts } from '../../api/ruuts/ruuts.js';
import { RuutsList } from '../components/ruuts-list.js';
import { Loading } from '../components/loading.js';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

const composer = (params, onData) => {
  let search = getParameterByName('s');
  if (search == null) {
    search = "";
  }
  const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('ruuts', search);
  if (subscription.ready()) {
    const ruuts = Ruuts.find({ ownerId: Meteor.userId() }, { sort: { title: 1 } }).fetch();
    onData(null, { ruuts });
  }
};

export default composeWithTracker(composer, Loading)(RuutsList);

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
  if (!url) {
    url = window.location.href;
  }
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
      results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

and here's the search component

```
import React from 'react';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';

export const SearchRuuts = React.createClass({
    handleSearch(e) {
        this.props.router.push({
            ...this.props.location,
            query: {s: e.target.value}
        });
    },

    render() {
      return <FormGroup className="search-ruut">
        <FormControl
          type="text"
          ref="searchRuut"
          onKeyUp={this.handleSearch}
          placeholder="Search by Requisition Number or Title"
        />
      </FormGroup>
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your normal onKeyUp handler in `_.debounce`:

```
onKeyUp={_.debounce(this.handleSearch, 500)}
```

Comment: It’s probably better to do this in `constructor()` because that way, React gets the same handler and doesn’t remove the old listener and add a new one on each `render()`.

Comment: I would also love to have the user get feedback from typing into the input field displayed in the url bar right away, this way, they'll type and the query will only display after the debounce times out